# Convert svg animation to apng sequence

Tags: svg, imagemagick, transparency, svg-animate, apng

Is there any way to do this?

I tried `magick -background none in.svg out.png` with `ImageMagick 7.1.0-61`, it removed the transparency and only kept the first frame of animation.

Comment: Post a link to your svg file. Be sure that you have Inkscape installed so that IM uses it in preference to MSVG or RSVG delegate. I am unaware that IM knows about SVG animations. But I am not an expert on that aspect.

Comment: https://svgshare.com/i/qJt.svg It only works for the first frame. I have Inkscape 1.2.2 (732a01da63, 2022-12-09) installed. Is there any other way besides ImageMagick?

Comment: Inkscape and RSVG do not support animations. See https://inkscape.org/learn/animation/ and https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/librsvg/Rsvg-2.0/overview.html. So Imagemagick will not support it either.  Sorry, I could not find any tools that will export an SVG animation to GIF or PNG individual frames or animation. The browsers will show it animated but not export to anything other than SVG. Perhaps someone else knows. I found references to other tools that appear to do that but they are not free. But I may have missed something.

Comment: I found https://html5animationtogif.com/svg-to-gif, but it did not work on your file. Seems to need an HTML page as well. You can check it out.

Comment: What paid tools can do this?

Comment: Don't recall. Perhaps I misunderstood.  Search Google and see what you find.